# How to filter out all short strings (2 and lower chars) in a corpus?

Tags: r, nlp, tm, corpus, qdap

Given a simple string:

```
t <- "hello world ww ff a wr gj dkjffdkn kuku"

VCorpus(VectorSource(t))
```

I want to filter out all the 2 and lower length substrings.
How can I do this using `qdap` or `tm` packages?
I know I can use `regex` for this but is there a function that does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the package `qdapRegex`, you can do:

```
rm_nchar_words(t, "1,2")

[1] "hello world dkjffdkn kuku"
```